# I need to know if I'm being called a b-word

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, offensive-language, learning

If I say to someone "please stop your bitching." Or "ugh all she does is bitch" does that imply that the person described is a bitch?

Comment: "To bitch" means something else than "to be a bitch". This is probably more suitable for [ell.se]

Comment: One of the changes I have seen in the 69 years I have been alive as a British English speaker, is the change in status of the word 'bitch'. As a derogatory term for a woman, in my childhood and early adulthood, it was spelt (spelled) in full. I have a feeling it was mainly used by women against other women; my mother used it freely about those she did not like. If the 'letterisation' of it (i.e. having to write and say 'the B word) reflects a more progressive attitude about misogynistic terms, then that's good. I know a female dog breeder who gets angry when told not to say it.

Answer (score 2):

As a *noun*, the word "bitch" means (among other things)

> an unkind or unpleasant woman

([source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bitch))

... and this is what you're concerned about people calling you.

But as a *verb*, the meaning is different:

> to complain and make unkind remarks about someone or something

([source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bitch))

That is: "bitching" means "complaining" rather than specifically "being a bitch (unpleasant woman)". Of course, an unpleasant woman may complain a lot, and make unkind remarks, but so do plenty of people (men and women alike) who wouldn't be described as bitches. So, to answer your question directly: no, that doesn't imply that they think you're a bitch; it's still *possible* that they do, but you can't tell from this statement along.

Comment: 'Stop bitching' is still far more pejorative than 'Stop complaining', as bitching is complaining _spitefully_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It's certainly far less polite, no argument, but bitching doesn't necessarily mean complaining spitefully (eg in the dictionary entry I reference, for the corresponding noun sense, it has the example "Most of us enjoy having a (good) bitch from time to time", which doesn't convey to me that there's any spite involved).

Comment: Yes, there is the more playful downtoning. This word is among those where context and delivery make a huge difference to vulgarity level.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps. What is most likely happening is that in the case of ¨Please stop your bitching¨ is that they are simply asking you to stop doing something, albeit more vulgar. Basically, in the case of both of the example sentences, I think that ¨bitch or bitching¨ means ¨Goof around/Do something that they don´t like¨. It would probably be used for something they do not like, and are eager to express their distaste. In my case, it is very general.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bitching = grumbling, complaining, criticizing.